# ArithmeticException when divide const integer in Flink SQL

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

Flink throwed **ArithmeticException**(on-terminating decimal expansion no exact representable decimal result) when I executed below query:

```
SELECT productId, COUNT(order), COUNT(order)/100.0
From product
GROUP BY productId
```

I can't find a way from the document or google to get rid of this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Flink are you using? On the master branch, a query like yours runs without problems. In general, StackOverflow is not a good place to report bugs. I'd suggest to open a [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/FLINK) and provide more information such as Flink version and the full stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Sure, will do that in future, I am using Flink 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception will be fixed in the upcoming Flink 1.5 release. It is described [in this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-8821). As a workaround you can simply cast to double precision `CAST(x AS DOUBLE)`. Only arithmetics on Java's `BigDecimal` type (SQL `DECIMAL`) are affected.